# Kryo deserialization Buffer underflow when class adds new field

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kryo

I have a java class serialized using kryo-shaded 4.0.1

class definition :

```
class A{
private int c1;
  private Map<Integer, String> c2;
}
```

After serialization when I deserialized its fine,But if If after serilization using existing definition and then add new field as

```
class A{
private int c1;
  private Map<Integer, String> c2;
private Map<Integer, String> c3;
}
```

And then tries to deserialize existing serialized content(serialized using old definition) it throws

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
Serialization trace:
....
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:199)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readVarInt(Input.java:373)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:127)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:693)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:543)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:709)
```

My code is thread safe as I am using Kryopool.
Does kryo not support schema evolution.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?